# How do I properly ground AC terminal blocks on a DIN rail and respective back plane?

Tags: ac, grounding, enclosure

I am building an electrical panel with AC and DC supplied power. My AC ground wires connect to a green DIN rail connector which has metal on the bottom of this terminal and connects to the DIN rail itself (which then is connected to the overall enclosure via back plane).

If I have 3 separate DIN rails all mounted to the same backplane, do I need to ground each individual (6 inch) rail? (for example: Connect AC ground to only ONE green DIN terminal block (which grounds the entire backplane) OR for each DIN rail (all on same metal back plane), attach a green ground DIN block to each individual 6 inch rail and wire the AC ground line to that particular rail?

NOTE: Schematic shows this terminal block only being ground 1x...I have grounded this 4x for 4 separate DIN rails (ALL on the same backplane)

Schematic attached (see RED outline box for ground terminal block).

[image]

Comment: I would want to make sure that all the DIN rails are securely grounded to the back panel.  If the panel is painted, the screws mounting the DIN rails may not ensure that the rails make good electrical contact with the panel.

Comment: @PeterBennett my thoughts as well. Thanks for the help on this. Follow up question- would I use the same DIN terminal blocks to ground DC "-" wiring? Or would I want to use the standard gray DIN terminal blocks to create a 12V and separate 5V "-" terminal bus via jumpers from terminal block to block?

Comment: That depends on whether you want the DC negatives to be connected to Earth/Safety Ground or not.  It might be desireable to create a DC Ground bus using standard terminal blocks, then connect that bus to the Safety Ground with a wire - makes it easy to change your mind about grounding...

Comment: @PeterBennett All very great points. Would these DC connections already be grounded due to the PSU being AC grounded? Any specific reasons I would not want the DC negatives connected to Earth/Safety in this case? Have researched this topic but appears to be up for negotiation without a clear answer whether to or not to ground DC negatives.

Comment: I think the DC outputs of the power supplies I've used have been isolated - no connection to the AC Safety Ground.  Thiis allows the user to use them as either positive or negative supplies.

Comment: @PeterBennett Got it. Thanks again Peter! Very helpful