# How do I properly ground DC and AC in the same enclosure (DIN rail)?

Tags: ac, dc, grounding, enclosure

I am building an electrical panel with AC and DC supplied power. My AC ground wires connect to a green DIN rail connector which has metal on the bottom of this terminal and connects to the DIN rail itself (which then is connected to the overall enclosure via back plane).

**2 questions:**

1. For DC ground, should I use the same green DIN mounts as I am using for AC? OR should I use the standard gray terminal blocks as the "-" terminal block that all PSUs can share (use jumpers across several of these blocks)? I am using 12V and 5V PSUs(see schematic).
2. If I should use the gray blocks, do I need separate "-" blocks for the 12V and 5V PSUs

Schematic attached. [image]

Comment: I don't know what electric codes require, and this might be opinion-based, but I'd simply reserve the green block for connecting yellow-green wires for setting the earth potential and connect all the earth nodes together, so that under normal use, there is no current via green block. If you connect DC grounds to same block, you have always DC current in the green block. Sure you can earth the gray DC return busbar if the power supplies already don't. Also the wifi light is accidentally connected to mains earth, it shouldn't.

Comment: What do you mean by AC ground?

Comment: This seems to be a repeat of your earlier question: [How do I properly ground AC terminal blocks on a DIN rail and respective back plane?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/533650/how-do-i-properly-ground-ac-terminal-blocks-on-a-din-rail-and-respective-back-pl)